# WPF Window Drag/Move Boundary

Tags: wpf, winforms

just curious if you know of any way to setup a drag boundary for a window?

It would be nice to have these properties:

```
Me.MinLeft = 10
Me.MinTop = 10
Me.MaxLeft = 150
Me.MaxTop = 150
```

**Those are made up properties, btw**, which would be nice to have.

I know I could probably setup a timer to fire ever 10th of a second and check the left and top and then move it back if it's over.  But it would be more elegant to have the  window act like it hit a wall and can't go any farther, like moving to the edge of the screen or something similar.

Edit: There seems to be some confusion somewhere, the point I'm trying to make is in the paragraph above, dragging, not re-sizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have no doubt that Nir's answer will work spending a little time implementing it, I was able to do what I wanted a little bit more elegant with this code:

```
Private Sub myWindow_LocationChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LocationChanged

    Dim primaryBounds As System.Drawing.Rectangle = Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    Dim windowBounds As System.Drawing.Rectangle = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(CInt(Me.Left), CInt(Me.Top), CInt(Me.Width), CInt(Me.Height))

    If (windowBounds.Left < 0) Then
        windowBounds = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, windowBounds.Top, windowBounds.Width, windowBounds.Height)
    ElseIf (windowBounds.Right > primaryBounds.Right) Then
        windowBounds = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(primaryBounds.Right - windowBounds.Width, windowBounds.Top, windowBounds.Width, windowBounds.Height)
    End If

    If (windowBounds.Top < 0) Then
        windowBounds = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(windowBounds.Left, 0, windowBounds.Width, windowBounds.Height)
    ElseIf (windowBounds.Bottom > primaryBounds.Bottom) Then
        windowBounds = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(windowBounds.Left, primaryBounds.Bottom - windowBounds.Height, windowBounds.Width, windowBounds.Height)
    End If

    Me.Left = windowBounds.Left
    Me.Top = windowBounds.Top

End Sub
```

This made the window being dragged stay within the primary screen (whole window), but you could easily change the bounds to whatever values you needed.

Comment: I've tried this before but the Window_LocationChanged event happens AFTER the window has already moved on the screen, so this creates a jarring visual effect where the window kind of flickers or jumps when it starts to go over some limit, because it initially gets drawn "out of bounds" and then redrawn back where you want it.

Comment: How to prevent the flickering of the window?The drag motion is not smooth.

Answer (score 3):

Here is teh "magic" you need to create this functionality, all you have to do is set the Window_SourceInitialized method to the window's SourceInitialized event and insert you logic where the big comment is.

I combined this code from several sources, so there could be some syntax errors in it.

```
internal enum WM
{
   WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046,
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct WINDOWPOS
{
   public IntPtr hwnd;
   public IntPtr hwndInsertAfter;
   public int x;
   public int y;
   public int cx;
   public int cy;
   public int flags;
}

private void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
   HwndSource hwndSource = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual((Window)sender);
   hwndSource.AddHook(DragHook);
}

private static IntPtr DragHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handeled)
{
   switch ((WM)msg)
   {
      case WM.WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
      {
          WINDOWPOS pos = (WINDOWPOS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(WINDOWPOS));
          if ((pos.flags & (int)SWP.NOMOVE) != 0)
          {
              return IntPtr.Zero;
          }

          Window wnd = (Window)HwndSource.FromHwnd(hwnd).RootVisual;
          if (wnd == null)
          {
             return IntPtr.Zero;
          }

          bool changedPos = false;

          // ***********************
          // Here you check the values inside the pos structure
          // if you want to override tehm just change the pos
          // structure and set changedPos to true
          // ***********************

          if (!changedPos)
          {
             return IntPtr.Zero;
          }

          Marshal.StructureToPtr(pos, lParam, true);
          handeled = true;
       }
       break;
   }

   return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Comment: Hi. What is `SWP` in if `((pos.flags & (int)SWP.NOMOVE) != 0)`?
it should be declared as an enum right?
`internal enum SWP
{
    NOMOVE = 0x0002
}`

Can you give a working example please?

Answer (score 0):

There are dependency properties for WPF's Window for this purpose.

Here they are:

- Window.MaxWidth
- Window.MaxHeight

These properties will constrain the size of the Window, just like the WinForm's Form.

Comment: I'm speaking of dragging a window around the screen, not re-sizing it.  Think of setting a region on the screen the window is only allowed to move round in, even though your screen is bigger.  Like a drag container is best I can think of.

Comment: I'm sitting here reading this again and wondering if I asked the question wrong and how you could think I was speaking of window size and not dragging, I don't even mention the word "size" or "re-size" in my question...

Comment: Drag boundary? I think it's by default is draggable. Do you want drag handle like the ones in the Windows Forms?

Comment: He wants to constraint the area within which a window can be dragged.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could handle [`PreviewMouseMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousemove.aspx) (either the event or override the corresponding protected method) and set `e.Handled = true` whenever the mouse movement would cause the window to move outside the region you want to constrain it to.

This seems like the most logical, WPF-like way of doing this.